# Explicit invariant subspaces in tensor product of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $L(\lambda)$ be an irreducible highest weight $\lambda$ representation of $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak{sl}_2$ with dimension $\lambda + 1$. I am interested in the $\hom$-space,
$$\hom_{\mathfrak g} (L(\mu)^* \otimes L(\lambda) \otimes L(\mu),\mathbb C) \cong \hom_{\mathfrak g}(\mathbb C,\mathbb C)$$

where we identify, $L(0) \cong \mathbb C$. If $\psi \in \hom_{\mathfrak g} (L(\mu)^* \otimes L(\lambda) \otimes L(\mu),\mathbb C)$ then $\psi \circ f \in \hom_{\mathfrak g}(\mathbb C, \mathbb C)$, where,

$$f : \mathbb C \to L(\mu)^* \otimes L(\lambda) \otimes L(\mu).$$

Now Clebsch-Gordan theory tells me how to decompose $L(\mu)^* \otimes L(\lambda) \otimes L(\mu)$ as a direct sum of irreducibles, but it does not give me explicitly what the invariant subspaces are, just making use of them being isomorphic to irreducibles.

However, I would like to explicitly construct $\psi \circ f$, so is there a general way to find how the trivial module embeds in a tensor product of irreducibles?

(I know that $\psi \circ f$ will be the identity up to a constant, but I have a $\psi$ so I need $f$ to be able to use that $\psi \circ f = \mathrm{id}$.)

Comment: What is $\mu$ here? Also shouldn't there be a parity issue here? Like if $\lambda$ is odd this tensor product should have no copies of the $L(0)$.

Comment: @Nate $\mu$ is also a weight, and yes $\lambda$ is assumed even.

Comment: $SL_2$ reps are self-dual, so what is the point of putting a $\ast$ on the first $L(\mu)$?